# Wait for promise to resolve and do something else while it does

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have a function that does two things something takes I/O time and I want to return it second but I want the other thing to process in this time and send quickly even if the first did not finish yet

```
getuser(x){
    let username = getUsernameDB(x.id);//takes time to get data it is an async function

    sendMessage(x.id,() => {//send message with callback function when it is recived
       sendMessage(username);//must wait for getUsernameFromDatabase
    });

}

async getUsernameDB(id){
return await this.dataaccess.getUsernameByUserId(id);//this returns new Promise
}
```

So I want mainly to make a promise, execute other code then wait here for this promise to resolve then continue.

Comment: `Wait for promise to resolve and do something else while it does` - yep, that's how promises work ... `the thread.join trick` the what now?

Comment: `let username = getUsernameDB(x.id);//takes time to get data it is an async function` ... so you want to wait for `getUsernameDB(x.id)` to finish before assigning anything to `username` .. right? and how do you know *when* `getUsernameDB` is finished? does it return a Promise? does it take a callback? what is that function? something you wrote? there's not enough information in the question to successfully help you

Comment: Question edited sorry for the missing function. What I want is to hold here tell the promise is resolved and the username has a value

Comment: `let username = await getUsernameDB(x.id)`, this will do what you need.

Comment: Actually that will just throw a syntax error.

Comment: So which promise do you want to not wait for, and what is the "something else" you want to do in the meantime? None of that seems applicable here.

Comment: @sanjeev actually this can be done but then even the first sendMessage will wait for the DB request while it doesn't need it

Comment: Then fetch the username when needed like `    sendMessage(x.id,() => 
       let username = await getUsernameDB(x.id)
       sendMessage(username);
    });`

Comment: @GrantGryczan I want it to do getUsernameDB and while it is getting it I will sendMessage and in it's callback I will sendMessage(userName). but I want to make sure that it is returned

Comment: @sanjeev that will make it first send the message then fetch then send the message .. I want it to fetch (while fetching send the first message) then when fetching done send the second message
if fetching and sending message takes 1 sec each what you are saying will take 3 seconds .. I want to do it in 2

Comment: `username` is currently a promise, so...
I understand where sanjeev is coming from, but I think that's just what they meant to put originally, not what will solve their issue. (Also it would still cause a syntax error.)

Comment: How to resolve?

Answer (score -1):

The .then should be put after the first sendmessage call. This will make the promise function run parallel with sendmessage then wait to resolve before sending the second message

```
getuser(x){
    let username = getUsernameDB(x.id);//takes time to get data it is an async function

    sendMessage(x.id,() => {//send message with callback function when it is recived
        username.then((usernameVar) => {
            sendMessage(usernameVar);//usernameVar is carring the value now
    })

    });

}

async getUsernameDB(id){
return await this.dataaccess.getUsernameByUserId(id);//this returns new Promise
}
```

Comment: This case will fail in case `getUsername` is completed before `sendMessage`. For example if `getUsername` take 0.1 second to complete and sendMessage take 0.2 second to complete.